# How to make condition true if array dont have element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if `selectedOwners` length is `>` `0` i want to set `selectedOwnerDisplay` falg true when page initially load it is set to false. For `addOwner` its working good but for `deleteOwner` its not hiding grid when `selectedOwners` length is`<` `0`.

Any idea what is wrong with below code ?

Any better way to implement these conditions ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div kendo-grid="selectedOwner" ng-show="selectedOwnerDisplay" k-options="selectedOwnerGridOptions" k-rebind="selectedOwnerGrid"></div>
        </div>
```

ctrl.js

```
 var selectedOwners = [];
 $scope.selectedOwnerDisplay = false;
$scope.deleteOwner = function(dataItem) {
      angular.forEach(selectedOwners, function(owner, $index) {
        if (owner.workerKey === dataItem.workerKey) {
            selectedOwners.splice($index, 1);
        }

    });
     if(selectedOwners.length < 0){
          $scope.selectedOwnerDisplay = false;
        }
   }
    $scope.addOwner = function(dataItem){
       if(selectedOwners.length > 0){
          $scope.selectedOwnerDisplay = true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You don't have to check the condition inside the forEach loop, do it after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eat your angular in wrong way :)

You should't try to check selectedOwnerDisplay, just use

```
ng-show="selectedOwners.length"
```

and, of course, set selectedOwners in scope.

Comment: in this case you can use deffered requests, that automatically rendered to view, just after server response.

Comment: Thank you so much i definitely learned something new today, this reduce alot of code.

Answer (score 1):

The array length can not be less than zero, you probably need this:

```
if (selectedOwners.length === 0) { // or selectedOwners.length < 1
    $scope.selectedOwnerDisplay = true;
}
```

Comment: Above problem solved using your answer but i see error in console  `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined` any idea why i have this once kendo grid is hidden

Comment: It is not possible to say looking at the code in your question, there are no references to the `classList`. Check where the error points, probably you have something like `myVar.classList` and `myVar` is undefined. In general, it looks like the new problem is not related to this question, so it may be better to post another question with error text and relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the help above problem resolved with your answer!